# WPF schema - what defines a ListBox to have a ScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, xaml, schema

For years, I have felt I don't have a good understanding of WPF because I haven't found an authoritative reference on the possibilities.  For example, I just found out that a `ListBox` has an attached `ScrollViewer` property.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

Other than reading a book or article that tells that, how would I know that `ScrollViewer` is a valid attached property?  Is there a XAML schema document or something?  How does Visual Studio Designer know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrollViewer` isn't an attached property; it's a class.

`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` is an attached property. But it's not an attached property that `ListBox` "has"; it's an attached property that can be attached to any `DependencyObject` at all, including `ListBox`.

Here's what you see if you right click on `ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `ScrollViewer.GetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility`. A pair of static methods like this is required for an attached property. The first parameter is the thing you're attaching the property to. It doesn't have to be `DependencyObject`; it could be `FrameworkElement`, `ListBox`, `ItemsControl`, or anything else that can support dependency properties.

```
// Summary:
//     Sets the value of the System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
//     dependency property to a given element.
//
// Parameters:
//   element:
//     The element on which to set the property value.
//
//   horizontalScrollBarVisibility:
//     The property value to set.
public static void SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(DependencyObject element, ScrollBarVisibility horizontalScrollBarVisibility);

//
// Summary:
//     Gets the value of the System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
//     dependency property from a given element.
//
// Parameters:
//   element:
//     The element from which the property value is read.
//
// Returns:
//     The value of the System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
//     dependency property.
public static ScrollBarVisibility GetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(DependencyObject element);
```

The `ListBox` itself quite likely has no clue what `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` means, or even that it exists. But in the `ListBox`'s template, there's probably a `ScrollViewer`, which will probably have a binding a lot like this:

```
<ScrollViewer
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
```

Put that attached property on any control that might have a `ScrollViewer` in its template, and if the template was written correctly, the `ScrollViewer` will use that value.

This is really, really nice because `ListBox` doesn't have to think about its own scrolling behavior. That's all delegated. Building controls by composition is extremely powerful.

The downside is that the whole thing is just a vast box of undifferentiated barf and it's real hard to make sense out of stuff. Intellisense can't tell you much about the scrolling behavior of `ListBox` when nobody outside *that particular `ListBox`'s template at the moment* can even guess what that scrolling behavior might be.

**So, in answer to your question: Yes. Basically you just have to read a lot of stuff.** And keep a "Cool XAML Tricks" text file to note down cool stuff you hear about that you don't have a use for just yet.

**But that's the way this profession has always been. Even with Intellisense, you can't use a class you don't know about.**

Today I learned about `ColumnDefinition.SharedSizeGroup` and `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`, and I learned that you can derive value converters from `MarkupExtension` and give them strongly typed, named properties instead of having to pass some goofy string into `CommandParameter`.

Comment: Thanks, it is is true that ListBox has a ScrollViewer, and it is that object's property that is being affected with `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollbarVisibility`.  While it is pretty obvious that a listbox would be able to scroll, it sure would be nice to spelunk that using IntelliSense or some other tool rather than stumbling on some doc, somewhere, someday, such as the `ColumnDefinition.SharedSizeGroup` that you just learned.  WPF is simply not discoverable the way Winforms controls are.  So when someone asks how good a WPF programmer I am, the answer is, I don't know.

Comment: @DavidChing ScrollViewers are how everything scrolls in WPF. One great way to learn is to right click on stuff in the XAML desginer view (this is the only thing I've ever found it useful for) and view their templates. But somebody could replace the template with one that doesn't have a ScrollViewer, and some nut could give a particular RadioButton a template that does have a ScrollViewer. The nature of it is that you have this big box of parts that can show up anywhere. It's not just that it isn't very well documented; it's that in a sense it's literally unknowable on a general level.

Comment: that's a great observation about it being unknowable, and tip about viewing the templates, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best docs we have right now are the **MSDN** documentation pages for WPF controls. For example, if you look up `ListBox`, you can find information about the attached `ScrollViewer`, and also it's full default template.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: That is a good start, thank you.  However, this makes no mention that it is possible to replace ListBox's default `ItemsPanel` which is a `VirtualizingStackPanel` with something like a regular `StackPanel`.  This is mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx), but it is not at all clear how I would get this page.

Comment: Correct, replacing templates is just part of the styling nature of WPF. You can replace the template of nearly every control.  I would possible recommend reading WPF unleashed, as it does go over template styling for controls.

Comment: I've bought many books, including that one.  :-)  What I am after is a definitive source of what is possible.  How does the Visual Studio XAML Designer IntelliSense work?  That seems to know just about everything legal there is in XAML.  As it is, my definition of WPF programming is using IntelliSense to stumble onto possibilities, then google what shows up....